# Python: import autobahn_autoreconnect causes RuntimeError

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-import, autobahn, reconnect

I want to use the module [autobahn-autoreconnect](https://github.com/isra17/autobahn-autoreconnect) and it works fine locally with PyCharm. I just install the module with PyCharm and exchange the old `ApplicationRunner` line with the new one:

```
# from autobahn.asyncio.wamp import ApplicationRunner
from autobahn_autoreconnect import ApplicationRunner
```

But when I install it on an Ubuntu server with `pip3 install autobahn-autoreconnect` and then use just `import autobahn_autoreconnect` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/autobahn_autoreconnect/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from autobahn.wamp import protocol
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/autobahn/wamp/protocol.py", line 272, in <module>
    class ApplicationSession(BaseSession):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/autobahn/wamp/protocol.py", line 277, in ApplicationSession
    log = txaio.make_logger()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/txaio/_unframework.py", line 43, in _throw_usage_error
    "To use txaio, you must first select a framework "
RuntimeError: To use txaio, you must first select a framework with .use_twisted() or .use_asyncio()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution worked for me.

First:

```
import txaio
txaio.use_asyncio()
```

Second:

```
from autobahn_autoreconnect import ApplicationRunner
```